# Understanding a very elementary property of factorials

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, factorial

I've seen this stated in a few places.

> If $$\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p\le{x}} \log (p) \qquad \psi(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\vartheta\left(\sqrt[m]{x}\right)$$ Then $$\log(x!) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \psi\left(\frac{x}{m}\right).$$

It is used by Ramanujan [here](http://www.imsc.res.in/%7Erao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper24/page1.htm). It is used by Jitsuro Nagura [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-28/issue-4/On-the-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number/10.3792/pja/1195570997.full).

Can anyone provide a proof for why it is true or provide a link to a proof?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We find

$$\sum_{m\ge1}\psi\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)=\sum_{m\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}\vartheta\left(\sqrt[k]{\frac{x}{m}}\right)=\sum_{m\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{p\le \sqrt[k]{x/m}}\log p$$

$$=\sum_{m\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{mp^k\le x}\log p=\log \prod_{p\le x}p^{\#\{(m,k):mp^k\le x\}}=\log x!$$

since when counting $\#\{(m,k):mp^k\le x\}$, one sees for every $1\le n\le x$ there are $t=v_p(n)$ different tuples $(m,t),(mp,t-1),\cdots,(mp^{t-1},1)$ counted in the set (note $k\ge1$).

Comment: Could you please expand a bit on your last paragraph? It looks to me like you're counting only the pairs $(m,v_p(n))$ with $m = 1$.

Comment: @A.P. Sorry, it's been two years so I don't quite remember what went wrong, but I suspect my brain might have went dark when typing out what I saw in my head. I've edited to give the correct list of tuples corresponding to each $1\le n\le x$. Basically, compute the sizes of the fibers of the obvious map $\{(m,k):mp^k\le x\}\to\{n:1\le n\le x\}$ given by $(m,k)\mapsto mp^k$ then sum the fibers' sizes.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. It still took me a while to parse your wording, so for the benefit of other here is how I see it: for every positive integer $n$ there are exactly $v_p(n)$ ways of writing $n$ as $m p^t$ with $m \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $t \geq 1$.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different variation based upon the prime factorisation of $x!$.

> We obtain for integers $x>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\log x!}&=\log\prod_{p\leq x}p^{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\cdots}\tag{1}\\
> &=\log\prod_{p\leq x}p^{\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^m}\right\rfloor}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{p\leq x}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\log p\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^m}\right\rfloor\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{p\leq \sqrt[m]{x}}\log p\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^m}\right\rfloor\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{p\leq \sqrt[m]{x}}\log p\sum_{j=1}^{x/p^m}1\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^x\sum_{p\leq \sqrt[m]{x}}\log p\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^x\psi\left(\frac{x}{j}\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we do the prime factorisation of $x!$ and observe that $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p}\right\rfloor$ counts the numbers $\leq x$ which are a multiple of $p$. Since we also have to add $1$ for each number which is a multiple of $p^2$ we add $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^2}\right\rfloor$, etc.
- In (2)  we use  the series notation. Note the series is finite.
- In (3) we use  properties of the logarithm.
- In (4) we exchange the order of the series.
- In (5) we write the factor $\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p^m}\right\rfloor$ as sum.
- In (6) we  exchange the order of the series again.

Comment: +1. It's a nice job.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Thanks Felix. This answer follows a proof which was given by E. Landau in 1909.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks because everyday we learn something new.

Comment: @FelixMarin: You're welcome. The same holds true for me. :-)